# which version of tcmalloc is used in gpertools-2.10

Tags: tcmalloc, gperftools

tcmalloc is one part of gperftools. I discover the version of tcmalloc used in gperftools laest version(currently 2.10) entirely different from tcmalloc from github: https://github.com/google/tcmalloc.

Anyone tells me the differenece between gperftools's tcmalloc and  libtcmalloc.so from LD_PRELOAD, and how gerftools interacts with tcmalloc(register hook?)

Comment: https://google.github.io/tcmalloc/gperftools.html, **Differences From Google’s Implementation of TCMalloc** maintenance burden is mentioned, but no more information is given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.